# Why did this photo of the Milky Way turn out badly?

Tags: astrophotography, milky-way

I followed [these instructions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37261/how-do-i-capture-the-milky-way) and written down the steps I understood to be important, that is:

```
shutter speed = 600 / focal length * crop factor (1.5 for APS-C sensors)
ISO = 6000 * f-stop^2 / shutter speed
```

So, I made my first photo of the Milky Way using the formulas to determine the exposure settings.
Now I'm undecided whether to go on or to throw myself off from a highway bridge :)

Is the problem with the photos below that there is too much light pollution (photo taken at 200 meters above the city), or did I do something wrong?

Here is the EXIF data:

```
Body: Nikon D7000 
Lens: Tokina 11-16mm F2.8 
Focal length: 11 mm 
F-stop: F2.8 
Shutter speed: 35 seconds 
ISO: 1250
```

Here you can see the result:

[image: The disaster !!!!]

For completeness I've also attached the lower part of the photo, just to let you see what the light was (real light)

[image: Real Light]

Note that the first photo (the wrong one) shows the upper part of the sky of the second photo.

Comment: With that many city lights, yes, the problem is pretty clearly light pollution.

Comment: Next time, find a place where you see *no* artificial lights, not even as a glow against the horizon, and try again :)

Comment: I only would like to be sure it was not an arror from me.
In some other groups (italy) i've been told to have used too much iso
;)

Comment: @user1653963: ISO is not a problem - you could probably push it to at least 3200. Of course, lower is better.

Comment: That looks a lot like light pollution. Try using a [light pollution map](http://darksitefinder.com/maps/europe.html) next time to find if a location is sufficiently dark.

Comment: I'm curious if you could see any indication of the Milky Way with the naked eye in that environment.  If the light pollution washes out what the eye can see, it will most certainly wash out the camera too.

Comment: You might try and see what sort of lights are still before dawn. At 4-5am there ought to be less cars, office lights etc.  That and a slightly better location might make a big difference.

Comment: Will your D7000 set  35 second shutter time? Did you use 30 seconds instead?

Comment: I used 35 sec because i calculated the shutter speed with the formula:
shutter speed = 600 / focal length * crop factor (1.5 for APS-C sensors)

Comment: I just stumbled on [two](http://petapixel.com/2014/07/29/photograph-milky-way-light-polluted-skies-singapore/) [tutorials](http://petapixel.com/2014/07/31/video-photoshop-tutorial-shows-exactly-capture-milky-way-heavy-light-pollution/) about photographing the milky way in an area that is light-polluted. Maybe you find the helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you have way too much light pollution. It looks like the sky is [Bortle class 7 or worse](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/light-pollution-and-astronomy-the-bortle-dark-sky-scale/)

> Class 7: Suburban/urban transition. The entire sky background has a vague, grayish white hue. Strong light sources are evident in all directions. The Milky Way is totally invisible or nearly so. M44 or M31 may be glimpsed with the unaided eye but are very indistinct. Clouds are brilliantly lit. Even in moderate-size telescopes, the brightest Messier objects are pale ghosts of their true selves. The naked-eye limiting magnitude is 5.0 if you really try, and a 32-cm reflector will barely reach 14th magnitude.

You need to move at least 50 km away from big cities to get dark enough skies to see the Milky Way well. Even at that distance away, you will still have a lot of light pollution causing the sky to turn blue in long exposure pictures. The milky Way will then be visible in the picture, but it will look like you somehow shot the picture during daytime or dusk.

A truly dark sky is only possible when you are at least a few hundred km away from cities, when the Moon is not in the sky and when the Sun is at least 18 degrees below the horizon. E.g. at 50 degrees Northern Lattitude around 21 june, the Sun does not sink far enough below the horizon, at local midnight you'll still have astronomical twilight. The sky may appear to look very dark with many faint stars visible, but weak nebulae will be drowned out.

Comment: Many years ago, I was in Death Valley ([Father Crowley Point](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Father+Crowley+Point/@35.526967,-117.0651089,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xf085f98b1a547a79)) and I could see two dim domes of light - one to the south, one to the east... and while the sky was full of stars, those two domes were enough that they took careful positioning of the frame to avoid contamination of a long exposure.

Comment: I dispute the 50km suggestion. On a clear night you can stand on a beach on east Hayling Island, UK and see the Milky Way with excellent clarity. The City of Portsmouth is 15km away. This may be because the city limits are the sea, limiting urban sprawl and providing a higher proportion of well controlled lighting fixtures.

Answer (score 3):

If you can see as little as the glow of lights of a small town over the horizon, you're going to suffer from light pollution to some extent. Light pollution is the reflection of the "glow" of cities off the atmosphere, brightening it, so dimmer stars can't be differentiated. If you see the clouds in your first picture, they're so bright because of the reflection from the city lights bellow. If you had taken the picture without a city beneath it, then the clouds would have been black.

From a quick glance, you're settings seem good, but with a city in your photo, it's not going to work without cheating, save maybe a freak blackout.

---

*Quick note, it's also worth noting that moon light is also a major contributor to light pollution. Probably not so much in this situation, but it's worth noting in the future.*

Comment: Perhaps unintuitively, sunlight may also be a major contributor at night. At even moderately high latitudes nights are *way* brighter in the summer than in the winter.

Comment: there wass no moon. here it's new moon. but of course, i see, too city lghts