# Not able to manual focus in night for star photography

Tags: lighting, manual-focus, night

I was shooting at f4.5 shutter speed 30s for capturing stars in my photo but was not able to manual focus as we can't set the manual focus for stars.

I am using a 18-55mm Nikkor lens, what I get after the image is captured is a bad focus image.

**Question:** If i am  not able to see the stars in the viewfinder then how can i set manual focus

Comment: What's 'f/30s' ? It's neither an aperture nor a time. Please edit your question to include all appropriate settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do the stars look so blurry? How can I improve the focus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/116680/why-do-the-stars-look-so-blurry-how-can-i-improve-the-focus)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to nail focus for DSLR astrophotography?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/23972)

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/119137/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focussing on a star with wide angle 14mm lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119137/focussing-on-a-star-with-wide-angle-14mm-lens)

Answer (score 3):

pre focus on a distant city light, or the Moon if out.

Answer (score 2):

Stars are at an infinite distance.

Failing to find a brighter similarily distant object (like a far tower with a light on it, or the Moon for instance), you can set your lens to infinity and hope that it works. In reality you likely will have to use a setting slightly less than the absolut maximum focus distance (how exact depends on your lens / camera combination and is subject to experience with your own equipment).

Comment: Calibrated hard infinity stops are rare on modern lenses. And it is better that way - drift in the wrong direction can make such a lens fail to focus at infinity at all. "Soft" stops also cannot be relied on until you really calibrated them, and did so taking temperature drift into account.

Comment: While that is true, the room for error gets larger the shorter the focal length. I hardly fail to manually adjust my fish eye to infinity without looking through. And with digital you can even take an image, review it, and re-adjust focus if needed