# Valid value for shutter speed based on Focal Length

Tags: lens, focal-length, shutter-speed

I was listening to Ben Long videos and he was saying a safe value for shutter speed is `1/focal length`
So if I have a `35mm prime 1.8` lens, does that mean `1/35 = 0.02` so in my camera panel do the values of shutter speed start as milliseconds? so if it is `20` it means 0.02?

Comment: Does [What is relationship between focal length and shutter speed?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46894/what-is-relationship-between-focal-length-and-shutter-speed) answer your question (in particular, the first answer to that question)?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yes, thanks. But so does 0.02 mean 20 for shutter speed?

Comment: In most (every?) camera I've ever used, 20 would mean 1/20s = 0.05s. But as you haven't told us which camera you're using, it's impossible for me to say - and this information should be in the manual anyway :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Nikon D-610

Comment: Also see [Where does the ¹/shutter speed = focal length rule for hand shake come from?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/where-does-the-%C2%B9-shutter-speed-focal-length-rule-for-hand-shake-come-from), although I don't think that's your question.

Comment: For the meaning of a displayed value of "20", you might ask that as a new question, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @mattdm : yeah exactly! that 20, I am under assumption that it means 20th of a second?

Comment: I suggest a new question "Do whole numbers for shutter speeds generally mean that they're milliseconds?" or similar. Because that's definitely a question you have in the comments here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are wrong:
1/35 is 0.03 seconds and you can use 1/30 sec. (as standard setting and very close to 1/35)
If you see 20 this mean 1/20 of the second. And with such speed there is probability you make blurry photos

Comment: so 1/30 sec .. then what Number does that mean on the camera panel for shutter speed?

Comment: Blake, this (1/30) of the second will be displayed on the camera viewfinder or liveview panel as number 30. In case your speed is in seconds will be displayed as 30'

Comment: awesome. That's what was confusing me as I was trying to convert that 1/30 to some other number on the viewfinder. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually even easier than that, since times below 0.3 seconds are commonly displayed as fractions of a second. So, "20" would be 1/20 second. Since you have a 35mm lens, that would correspond to 1/35 second or "35" (or the next higher available number). No need to go decimal here, just stay with fractions :)

Comment: so on my camera panel when it shows number 20, does that mean 20/100 of a second? or 20/1000 of a second ?

Comment: as i said, 1/20. which is 0.05 or 5/100 or 50/1000, but this seems rather useless info.