# Upgrade camera from Canon700d to 80d

Tags: canon-700d

Is it a good upgrade for me from my 700d to the 80d. Trying to get photos that bit sharper and crisp.

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50006/35348

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading from the 700D to the 80D might marginally improve your images, but getting photos that are sharp and crisp requires the right [shooting techniques](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp) and [good lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/how-can-i-take-crisp-sharp-shots-without-an-expensive-lens?rq=1). So the answer is, "No, it's not a good upgrade for you if you think changing cameras will make up for poor technique using the same lens(es)."

Comment: In addition to that, post processing might also play a role here