# How to inmediatly focus and take the shot quick

Tags: canon, autofocus

ive got a a canon t5i rebel.. im an amateur photographer. Basically when i shoot for example and normal picture i use the camera viewer point as usual but sometimes as i press the shutter button half and then during that process the image gets focus but when im gonna shoot it gets blurry. I dont know if im doing it wrong or which settings should i use or put in the menu. I wanna be able to just focus and shoot sharp and clearly. Btw im using autofocus.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you're seeing motion blur? What's the shutter speed and focal length on the blurred pictures?

Comment: Also related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/how-can-i-take-crisp-sharp-shots-without-an-expensive-lens

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61593/pictures-start-in-focus-then-go-out-of-focus/61597#61597

Comment: Unfortunately, use of "Gonna", "Wanna" and "BTW" means the question is invalid.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Joining you in muppets bald eagle judgemental mode: Sez who? BTW may confound the less erudite but gonna nd wanna r gud enuff to communicate even though they act as an impediemnt to societal acceptance in certain uptight circles. N'est pas?

Comment: That was a joke "btw" !